# Exact meaning and function of 冒頭のような

Tags: translation

In　がばいばあちゃん, I came across the phrase 冒頭のような, which I had a little trouble translating, as I couldn't quite make out its exact meaning and function. It comes from the following extract.

> そして俺は、冒頭のような、ばあちゃんとの暮らしの中から、人間の本当の幸せというものを学んできたように思う。

I had a crack at translating this with the following result.

> As for me, living alongside her and seeing things from there, as if I were right up close, I got to learn about true human happiness, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

冒頭 always refers to the first part/chapter of a story/article. So 冒頭のような暮らし means something like "my life as described in the first part (of this story)."

Answer (score 1):

> そして俺は、**冒頭のような**、ばあちゃんとの暮らしの中から、人間の本当の幸せというものを学んできたように思う。

the meaning of the phrase is what is written in naruto's answer, and it fully make sense, but we usually use it more precisely like:

> - 冒頭に**あった**ような
> - 冒頭に**記｛しる｝した**ような
> - 冒頭に**述｛の｝べた**ような